# `mkvirtualenv` doesn't work after install anaconda Python

Tags: python, virtualenv, anaconda, jupyter

Before I installed `anaconda`, I usually start project with `virtualenvwrapper` :

```
mkvirtualenv --python=python3.5 myproject
workon pystagram myproject
```

where `which python3.5` shows,

```
>> /usr/local/bin/python3.5
```

But, after I installed anaconda, system-based-python changed to ananconda versions. So, `which python3.5` shows,

```
>> /Users/Chois/anaconda/bin/python3.5
```

So, mkvirtualenv occurs errors :

```
Running virtualenv with interpreter /Users/Chois/anaconda/bin/python3.5
Using base prefix '/Users/Chois/anaconda'
New python executable in /Users/Chois/.virtualenvs/chois_jupyter/bin/python3.5
Also creating executable in /Users/Chois/.virtualenvs/chois_jupyter/bin/python
ERROR: The executable /Users/Chois/.virtualenvs/chois_jupyter/bin/python3.5 is not functioning
ERROR: It thinks sys.prefix is '/Users/Chois/.virtualenvs' (should be '/Users/Chois/.virtualenvs/chois_jupyter')
ERROR: virtualenv is not compatible with this system or executable
```

I think the best way I can use both `virtualenvwrapper` and `anaconda` is to do something like installing anaconda in virtual environment but as I know it is impossible.

What should I do?

(I usually do django-project in virtual-environment and start to study `jupyter` now)

Comment: Is it ok to create virtual environment using anaconda python?

Comment: anaconda comes with CONDA ,use that instead of virtualenv

Comment: @Bg1850 Is it ok to use that when I'm doing django project?

Comment: yeah why not  ? Although I am not a django person

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my previous setup of virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper after installing Anaconda/iPython.  The way I managed to get it to work is to activate only one at a time not both.  The changes I made when I need virtualenv or virtualenvwrapper:

1. edit .bash_profile
   `nano ~/.bash_profile`
   comment out the following line
   `#    export PATH="/Users/XXX/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`
2. Rename the anaconda folder to something else temporary.  `mv ~/anaconda3 ~/_anaconda3`
3. Restart your terminal.  virtualenv/virtualenvwrapper should be back again.

When you need anaconda back, revert the changes.